# Git: Can you see the differences between a specific file in the head vs working directory?

Tags: git, compare, git-diff

I forgot the exact changes I made and want to make my commit message based on said changes. So basically, I want to find out what those changes are.

Problem is, using diff is a bit problematic since I made this file in Visual Studio, and throws in a lot of other files with it.

Any way I can check the specific changes of some file `file.txt` specifically, between working directory and its version in a branch, say `master`, vs its version in my working directory?

Comment: `git diff HEAD -- path/to/file` should do it (or `git diff master -- path/to/file`). The `--` is to make sure that Git does not treat the file name as a branch name or commit specifier, if it happens to be valid as one.

Answer (score 0):

In addition of the command line, you could use plugins like [Git Diff Margin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LaurentKempe.GitDiffMargin)

> Git Diff Margin displays live Git changes of the currently edited file on Visual Studio margin and scroll bar.

[image: https://laurentkempe.gallerycdn.vsassets.io/extensions/laurentkempe/gitdiffmargin/3.5.2.54/1500682511088/142621/1/gitdiffmargin-preview.png]